# How can defs be referenced in an external SVG file's symbol?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to reference a `linearGradient` as a `fill` on a path inside of a `symbol` in an external SVG file.

The problem is that the `linearGradient` is not being recognized, even though it's in the same SVG document as the symbol.

You can see what I'm trying to accomplish here, with this JCB credit card SVG file: https://plnkr.co/edit/oJqodymkpHX7DHXD6b0d?p=preview

It's not recognizing the `linearGradient`s inside the `symbol` `path`s and so it's not rendering properly.

**How can `def`s be referenced in an external SVG file's `symbol`?**

I'm currently developing in Chrome 54.

You can see how the JCB SVG is supposed to look here (and how it is working properly when not as an external SVG file): https://plnkr.co/edit/XiFBUmvyC47XnCW6gXFx?p=preview

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug, why not report it to their bugtracker?